# Typescript Argument of type is not assignable to parameter of type 'Partial<unknown> & Attributes'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

So I have a component that I need to override in one particular case to pass some props down to its child node, to do so I am using cloneElement, like so

```
const fixChildren = cloneElement(children,
{preSetCalculations: {itemWidth} })
```

however the {preSetCalculations: {itemWidth} } part of the code, gives the following typescript error

> No overload matches this call. The last overload gave the following
> error. Argument of type '{ preSetCalculations: { itemWidth: number; };
> }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Partial &
> Attributes'. Object literal may only specify known properties,  and
> 'preSetCalculations' does not exist in type  'Partial &
> Attributes'

.

So how do I handle this, note I need to handle basically any type of element and I don't necessarily know what props they take beforehand

Answer (score 0):

Ok well I found any answer for now, unless someone gives me something better, which is

```
const fixChildren = cloneElement(
children as any, 
{preSetCalculations: {itemWidth} 
});
```